# Unable to upload file after moving from .netcore 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a service that is built for uploading files.
There are 2 assemblies: the one with ApiController and the other with the logics.

Controller:

```
public async Task<UploadFileResponse> UploadFromUrl([Required] string url, [FromQuery] string policy = null)
{
    return await _fileStorageService.UploadFromUrlAsync(url, policy);
}
```

And the business:

```
public abstract class BaseFileStorageService<TOptions> : IFileStorageService
{
...
    public async Task<UploadFileResponse> UploadFromUrlAsync(string url, string policyName = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

        ... //http request for the file

        var fileDataStream = await downloadResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        if (contentLength == null)
            throw new Exception("File upload error");

        var formFile = new FormFile(fileDataStream, 0, contentLength.Value, null, fileName)
        {
            Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
            ContentType = contentType
        };
    }
}
```

I have added the following packages:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http v.2.2.2
and
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.2.0 (I've tried 3.1.2 but the behaviour is the same)

Both projects are built with .net core 3.1. The currently installed version is 3.1.102.

A can break with the debugger at the controller but when I am trying to fall inside the business logic, I'm getting the following message:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'
```

I spent a day struggling with the issue. And have no clue how to make it work.

What may be the reason and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference

It appears that is should be fixed manually.